# Is any better way to terminate chrome.exe on windows

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome

I want to programmatically exit Chrome.exe via C++ on Windows OS.

Now, I use Terminate() API, however, as Chrome.exe has many instances, when kill Chrome.exe, it will popup an UI which explains that an extension crashed. I think this is because we kill extension process.

So is there any graceful method that can make Chrome.exe exit. Thanks!

Comment: You could run the code `taskkill /f /im chrome.exe` using `system()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int CTestDlg::KillChromeProcess()
{
    HANDLE hProcessHandle;  
    ULONG nProcessID;
    HWND TheWindow;

    TheWindow = ::FindWindow( _T("Chrome_WidgetWin_1"), NULL );
    ::GetWindowThreadProcessId( TheWindow, &nProcessID );
    hProcessHandle = ::OpenProcess( PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, nProcessID );
    return ::TerminateProcess( hProcessHandle, 4 );
}
```

"Chrome_WidgetWin_1" you can use Spy++ to get.